# How to manipulate PPT with NPOI for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, npoi

I made a lot of researchs about how to manipulate **PPT** with `NPOI` dll for `.NET`, but the examples are only to manipulate **XLS** files.

Someone knows how to do it for **PPT**?

In fact, what i need exactly is to upload a ppt file, and save each slide of this ppt as a jpg.

Comment: NPOI 2.0 [only supports Excel and Word files](http://www.leniel.net/2014/01/npoi-2.0-major-features-enhancements-series-of-posts-scheduled.html#sthash.zechwAvL.dpbs). You can use the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278318.aspx) to work with PresentationML directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You know if the **Open XML SDK** is Free and have no costs to commercial purposes if i use it in a software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently NPOI does not support Powerpoint format (only some scratches of HSLF are done).

According to [roadmap](https://npoi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NPOI%20Road%20Map) powerpoint support has been planned at version 2.2 (current is 2.1.3)

Comment: That's sad. Now i see, in the [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) site they say that **E-iceblue** community have this resource, not NPOI. Thanks.